# Operations on data frame with a variable containing vectors

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

When I create a dataframe for which one variable contains a vector of integers, like

```
id <- 1:5
meas <- list(NA,c(1,2),c(1),c(1,2,3),c(1,2,3,4))
myDf <- data.frame(cbind(id,meas))
```

I can easily copy the vector into another variable or check if it contains a NA

```
myDf$copyMeas <- myDf$meas
myDf$naMeas <- is.na(myDf$meas)
```

but when I want to get the length of the vectors I get the number of observations in the data frame

```
myDf$lengthMeas <- length(myDf$meas)

  id       meas   copyMeas naMeas lengthMeas
1  1         NA         NA   TRUE          5
2  2       1, 2       1, 2  FALSE          5
3  3          1          1  FALSE          5
4  4    1, 2, 3    1, 2, 3  FALSE          5
5  5 1, 2, 3, 4 1, 2, 3, 4  FALSE          5
```

Why is this behaviour? What should I use when I want the length of the vectors in another variable?

Comment: You have a data.frame (which in itself is a list) of lists of lists. This structure in R is called `probably.looking.for.trouble`.

Comment: Bah, lists (of lists (of lists (maybe even of (more) lists))) are fine. You just need to make sure you have (sufficent (and necessary)) parentheses (of any sort) (sometimes (but not always) nested) handy.

Answer (score 1):

Because that column is a list. If you ask for the length of a list, you'll get how many elements it has. You seem to want the length of each element:

```
sapply(myDf$meas,length)
[1] 1 2 1 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick:

```
sapply(myDf$meas, length)
[1] 1 2 1 3 4
```

`length` is not vectorized, it assumes you want the length of the object you put into it. Using `sapply` you force that `length` is done for each entry in `myDf$meas`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

```
str(myDf)
```

and you will see that `myDf$meas` is still a `list`. Accordingly, the result of `length(myDf$meas)` is the length of this list, which is 5.

You are looking for

```
myDf$lengthMeas <- sapply(myDf$meas, length).
```

Comment: My misunderstanding in believing that a data frame will copy the variables in an own data structure and thereby dissolving this distinction.